# Javascript grammar in antlr4 and python

Tags: python, antlr4

I have used the following link for JavaScript grammar .

```
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/javascript/javascript/Python
```

i have used antlr4.8 and ntlr4-python3-runtime==4.8. when i use the following code it gives following error .

error:

```
PS N:\antlr4\sample\py4.8> python main.py test.js
Running
Test started for: test.js
Created parsers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "main.py", line 20, in main
    tree = parser.program()
  File "N:\antlr4\sample\py4.8\JavaScriptParser.py", line 880, in program
    self.enterRule(localctx, 0, self.RULE_program)
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\antlr4\Parser.py", line 366, in enterRule
    self._ctx.start = self._input.LT(1)
.
.
.
  File "N:\antlr4\sample\py4.8\JavaScriptLexer.py", line 919, in sempred
    return pred(localctx, predIndex)
  File "N:\antlr4\sample\py4.8\JavaScriptLexer.py", line 925, in HashBangLine_sempred
    return  this.IsStartOfFile()
NameError: name 'this' is not defined
```

code:

```
import sys
from antlr4 import *
import JavaScriptLexer
import JavaScriptParser

JSL = JavaScriptLexer.JavaScriptLexer
JSP = JavaScriptParser.JavaScriptParser

class WriteTreeListener(ParseTreeListener):
    def visitTerminal(self, node:TerminalNode):
        print ("Visit Terminal: " + str(node) + " - " + repr(node))

def main(argv):
    input_stream = FileStream(argv[1])
    print("Test started for: " + argv[1])
    lexer = JSL(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = JSP(stream)
    print("Created parsers")
    tree = parser.program()
    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(WriteTreeListener(), tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Running")
    main(sys.argv)

print("Hello")
```

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: `return !this.IsStrictMode()` is invalid syntax. It should've been `return not this.IsStrictMode()`.

Comment: @ForceBru that's right, thank you. i changed that and now gives me another error.

Comment: You might want to show the JS code you're trying, it's kind of important to the question, don't you think?

Comment: @Tomalak :) yess. my test.js => "a = 1"

Comment: The actions in the grammar aren't valid Python. You'll need to translate all of them to Python before you can use the grammar with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this` with `self`
[(ref here)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Example:

Change
`return  this.IsStartOfFile()`
to
`return  self.IsStartOfFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script `transformGrammar.py`, as indicated in documentation.